# Is there a function in Rust equivalent to Java's Stream.Iterate?

Tags: iterator, rust

Does the Rust standard library have a function that generates an infinite iterator given a seed and a lambda, as the Java 8 Streams provide? If not, what is a similar alternative in Rust?

```
Stream.iterate(1, x -> 2 * x);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Rust standard library [*used*](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/8d90d3f36871a00023cc1f313f91e351c287ca15) to have similar functionality under the name `unfold`, but it was never made stable and was eventually removed. It now lives in the [itertools crate](http://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/struct.Unfold.html):

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Unfold;

fn main() {
    let x = Unfold::new(1, |x| {
        *x *= 2;
        Some(*x)
    });

    for val in x.take(10) {
        println!("{}", val);
    }
}
```

Note that it's a bit more complicated because the state doesn't have to exactly match with what the iterator returns and you can control when the iterator **stops**. It's possible that the crate would accept a PR for a thin layer on top that gives your exact implementation.

Answer (score 7):

As of Rust 1.7, there's nothing in Rust's standard library that does the equivalent of `Stream.iterate` (or I couldn't find it!).

I just whipped up the following implementation in Rust. It's not as straightforward as the Java implementation might be, because we have to take care of ownership (hence the requirement for `Clone` and the `Option` dance with the `value` field).

```
struct SequenceGenerator<T, F> {
    value: Option<T>,
    calc_next: F,
}

impl<T, F> SequenceGenerator<T, F>
    where T: Clone,
          F: FnMut(T) -> T
{
    fn new(value: T, calc_next: F) -> SequenceGenerator<T, F> {
        SequenceGenerator {
            value: Some(value),
            calc_next: calc_next,
        }
    }
}

impl<T, F> Iterator for SequenceGenerator<T, F>
    where T: Clone,
          F: FnMut(T) -> T
{
    type Item = T;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let result = self.value.as_ref().unwrap().clone();
        self.value = Some((self.calc_next)(self.value.take().unwrap()));
        Some(result)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let seq_gen = SequenceGenerator::new(1, |x| 2 * x);
    for i in seq_gen.take(10) {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be wrapped in a crate, documented and submitted as TWiR's Crate of the Week.

Comment: I am wondering if it would not be easier to take `F: FnMut(&mut T)` instead of using the `take` dance.

Comment: Does the itertools crate already have this? Seems like it should.

Comment: It looks much neater with `F: FnMut(&mut T)` and `Option` removed from `value`, and `fn next(&mut self) -> Option<T> { let new_value = (self.calc_next)(&self.value); Some(mem::replace(&mut self.value, new_value)) }`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard [`scan`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.scan) iterator:

```
let seq_gen = iter::repeat(())
                      .scan(1, |r,_|{
                          let out = *r; *r = out * 2 ; Some(out)
                      });
```

or with explicit closure definition:

```
let seq_gen = iter::repeat(())
                      .scan((1, |x| x*2), |r,_|{
                          let out = r.0; r.0 = r.1(r.0); Some(out)
                      });
```

For *noncopyable* types things looks worse:

```
let seq_gen = iter::repeat(())
                      .scan(Some("Hello world".to_owned()), |r,_|{
                          let out = r.clone(); *r = r.take().map(|x| x+"!") ; out
                      });
```

For these types it is better to use functions that modify the value in place:

```
let seq_gen = iter::repeat(())
                      .scan("Hello world".to_owned(), |r,_|{
                          let out = r.clone(); r.push_str("!") ; Some(out)
                      });
```

Comment: Nice; however with `String` it would not work as is because you are unwittingly relying on the fact that `1` is `Copy` for `let out = r.0` to work I am afraid. The issue with `scan` is that it's not really meant for such a trick; the state remains the property of `scan` while you need to yield *values*.

Comment: @MatthieuM. but you could declare the `String` before the iterator and then use a `&mut String` as the state value, right?

Comment: @Shepmaster: possibly... I've played with something like a `&mut Option<T>` as state in a previous answer. It's not very elegant, but I think it can be made to work.

Comment: @MatthieuM. something like [this](http://is.gd/EvF5Kb). Also note the use of `iter::repeat` instead of the `Option` iter / cycle.

Comment: @Shepmaster: don't use integers, they're `Copy`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. well, OP does want Java semantics, so you could always wrap the `String` in an `Rc` and/or `RefCell` so you can return them *and* keep them as state ;-)

Comment: Completely forgot about `iter::repeat`. @Shepmaster, thank you for reminding. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if

```
fn main() {
    let x = (1..std::i32::MAX) .map(|x| x*2);

    for i in x {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

would be a satisfactory option for you.

Comment: Use 1.. (an open range) instead of std::i32::max, it never returns None